# DbContextPool and ChangeTracker events

Tags: entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I am learning how to use DbContextPool and ChangeTracker in my .NET Core 3.1 app.

Startup.cs

```
 services.AddDbContextPool<DmsContext>(
                options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database"))
                    .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention(),
                Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["DbContextPoolSize"])
                );
```

DmsContext.cs

```
....

public DmsContext(DbContextOptions<DmsContext> options)
         : base(options)
{
  //use to hook up additional functions to ChangeTracker events
  SubscribeStateChangeEvents();
}

...
private void SubscribeStateChangeEvents()
{
   ChangeTracker.Tracked += OnEntityTracked;
}

private void OnEntityTracked(object sender, EntityTrackedEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Hi");
}
```

The above setup seems to only print the message `Hi` for the first request after the server gets restarted. Subsequent requests, using the same context instance, do not trigger `OnEntityTracked` to run. To me, it seems like the ChangeTracker gets reset-ed when the context instance is returned to the pool.

What is the correct way to work with ChangeTracker events in a pooling setup like the above? Thanks.

Comment: Fixed: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19193 , Fix available in EF Core 6